# VPN To kick in for certain domains

Tags: macos, mac, vpn, openvpn

I'm using Tunnelblick for Mac, and I was wondering if it's possible to only limit VPN traffic to be routed for certain domains / or if there's a different way to limit it.  It slows down the rest of my connections pretty bad, but I feel like it shouldn't just be an all or nothing solution.

Answer (score 2):

VPN connections are located at the IP or TCP layer of the network stack. Domains are located at the application level. In consequence a VPN client such as tunnelblick cannot limit the traffic based on domains, as that concept is meaningless at the network level where tunnelblick works.

In order to do this you would have to look into using proxies, which can inspect the packets at the application layer and then make decisions on how to handle them.

Generally a slowdown would indicate that too much traffic is flowing over the VPN connection. This can happen if the VPN server is configured to route all traffic through the VPN instead of just the networks that you connect to. If you can post your routing table here, while connected to the VPN, then I can tell you more.

Comment: lol wolfie how do I get you the routing table?  not sure what the command is.. :)

Comment: A command to view your route table is `netstat -r -n`, the command to manipulate the table is `route`.

Answer (score 0):

the limitation should be done as network routes, and your administrator should mention the subnets that should be routed via the VPN connection in the server's configuration.

You can always change your the routing table using the `route` command.

Answer (score 0):

In case of openconnect, vpn-slice might help. Read more here:
https://gist.github.com/stefancocora/686bbce938f27ef72649a181e7bd0158

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers as the linked site might change, rendering your answer useless. Instead quote the most important parts from the site and provide the link for reference only.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there is a built-in mechanism in tunnelblick for doing this.
You may be able to achieve some rate limiting using 'ipfw' using the destination
networks to distinguish between VPNs or globally on VPN traffic.
eg [throttle bandwidth with ipfw](http://www.farawaymac.com/mac-server/throttle-bandwidth-on-a-mac-with-ipfw/)

There is also an app called [Speed Limit](http://mschrag.github.com/) which may be of some use though
I haven't used it for VPN traffic before.